# Is there a way to start Jack server when system detects that a USB Sound card is plugged in or add a usb headset to Jack server?

Tags: usb, 19.10, jack

Questions are :

- how to run a script when a USB device is plugged in ?
- how to detect if it is a USB Sound card in order to be able to start jackd on this device ?
- how to detect if it is a USB Headset in order to be able to add it to current jack using alsa_in and alsa_out or pulseaudio (jack bridge) ?

Comment: The secret word for tonight is `udev`. Start with `man -k udev`.

Comment: It seems that a great part (if not all) of these behaviours are implemented in Ubuntu studio.